# How can I inform a script called from a udev rule of the device that triggered the rule?

Tags: udev

I've got a udev rule

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="vd[c-z]", ENV{DEVICE_NAME}="KERNEL" RUN+="/usr/local/bin/udevtest"
```

where devices vd[c-z] trigger the rule and call my script. I am trying to pass the exact name of the device that triggers the script with the $DEVICE_NAME environment variable but it doesn't seem to be being picked up by the called script.

How is this done?

I am trying to write this for Debian and Ubuntu, so I don't think udisks2 can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using an environment variable, can you pass it in to the script as an argument? Something like:

```
RUN+="/usr/local/bin/udevtest %k"
RUN+="/usr/local/bin/udevtest $KERNEL"
```

Assuming your script can be modified to handle arguments

Comment: YES. I should've  read man 5  udev, the section that starts with:
`The NAME, SYMLINK, PROGRAM, OWNER, GROUP, MODE and RUN fields support simple string substitutions.`